# Handling Dialogue Actions in Excel through Macros

Tags: vba, excel

I have a command button in Excel which opens up a dialogue with <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd> options, Here I have to click on <kbd>OK</kbd>. Can you please help me with this ?

Attaching screen shot for referance, after clicking on submit button it's opening the box, where I have to chose an option, which is not getting recorded in macros actions

[image]

Comment: What dialog is it opening?

Comment: Can you exlain a bit more?

Comment: Maybe - `Do: Loop Until MsgBox("Must press ok", vbOKCancel) = vbOK`.  The loop won't exit until you press OK.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not clear, what you have provided could be interpreted with the following code in VBA:

```
Sub Sheet1_Button1_Click()
    'Code goes here
    MsgBox "MUST click OK", vbOKOnly
    'More code goes here
End Sub
```

If attached to a Button form on `Sheet1`, this will produce a message box that says "MUST click OK". There will be an OK button there. Let us know if this answers your question.